# Select a P12 certificate (out of many loaded) based upon specific Chrome profile?

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-chromedriver

Automating Chrome tests with Chromedriver, we have multiple profiles with different permissions. There are multiple P12 certificates loaded (1 for each profile). How do I get java to choose the one that is tied to a specific profile?

Hi, please point me to a FAQ or answered question, I've looked but can't find what I need.

I'm trying to automate some tests using Chromedriver, and I have multiple profiles EACH with its own P12 certificate for logging into our target web site. For example, ChromeProfileA uses certA.p12 to access the target web site, but ChromeProfileB (with different permissions, etc.) uses certB.p12  to access that same web site.

I understand the registry entry process to create a filter for a SINGLE certificate, but, I can't see how to select one specific certificate from a list of certs, based upon the profile that Chrome was launched with.

Thanks!
Dennis

Comment: If I understand correctly you need to launch specific Chrome profile to be able to use specific certificate? In that case just create new driver instance with profile folder. Like this: ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
options.addArguments("user-data-dir=" + path2profileAsString);

Comment: @pburgr You understand correctly, and, I am using the user-data-dir argument when launching the browser.  What happens is that when I then try and go to our target web site, I get the Windows "select a certificate" popup, which I can't easily control with my automation tools.   ---  Is there a place in the User Data directory to put a certificate, so that when  web site needs one it just looks in the right spot vs. interactively asking for one?  I can't seem to find a folder named "Certificates" or some obvious name like that :)

Comment: You need open chrome with desired profile and perform the select manualy (avoid the pop-up). There is a difference between imported certificate and remembered certificate on a page.

Comment: Can you provide URL?

Comment: I don't understand your previous comment, "....perform the select manualy (avoid the pop-up) ..."

Comment: I'm attempting to automate a large number of tests, so, a person can't be involved during test execution.

Comment: If the page can remember used certificate, you need to login manualy just once. If the page requires certificate imported in browser, you need to import it just once (for each profile/certificate).